# SSL verification fails for apex domain using route 53 with aws load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2

```
Secure Connection Failed

An error occurred during a connection to domain.com. PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
    Please contact the web site owners to inform them of this problem.
```

I am getting this error only for root domain. My subdomains are working well. My ssl certificate is for `*.domain.com`, I tried using `domain.com` ssl certificate but this is giving me insecure connection on subdomain as well as root domain.

The website loads on brave and chrome browser after reloading 3 times. Initial 2 hits give the same error. This is giving consistent error on firefox.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the documentation for AWS ACM (you are likely using this with your AWS load balancer) you will find the following:

> When you request a wild-card certificate, the asterisk (*) must be in the leftmost position of the domain name and can protect only one subdomain level. For example, *.example.com can protect login.example.com, and test.example.com, but it cannot protect test.login.example.com. Also note that *.example.com protects only the subdomains of example.com, it does not protect the bare or apex domain (example.com). To protect both, see the next step.

So in this case, you are able to protect `*.domain.com` but `domain.com` is not part of this wildcard, which is why you are seeing the error. To resolve this, you'll want to create a certificate with both `*.domain.com` and `domain.com` so that you can serve HTTPS traffic from your subdomains and apex domain.

Further information on how to do this can be found in this document:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html

Specifically this section:

> 3. To add another name, choose Add another name to this certificate and type the name in the text box. This is useful for protecting both a bare or apex domain (such as example.com) and its subdomains such as *.example.com).

Comment: yes,, i had created both certificates,, then left it overnight and now its working,, probably dns propagation did its job,, thanks :)